# C++ - Error - No operator "[]" matches these operands

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on code for a container that stores strings and sorts them in alphabetical order (thought that it'd be a fun idea). I've been attempting to put a "[]" operator and assign it to the private member *words* so I can access any data or strings inside of said member. However, I've been struggling with this continuous error that I'm having trouble fixing. It says:

```
No operator "[]" matches these operands. Operand types are std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>>[size_t]
```

Here's some of the code regarding the error (Error is present at class.cpp):

***class.h***

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class sort
{
public:

//...


    sort(int i): words(std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(i)) { } 

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> & operator [](size_t st);

//...

private:

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> words;
    std::string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

};
```

***class.cpp***

```
#include "sort.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//...

std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> & sort::operator[](size_t st) 
{

    return words[st]; //Error is defined at the brackets
}

//...
```

Another thing to note is that if I remove the brackets with `st`, the error is gone (Obviously not what I'm trying to achieve). Any help or a fix to this code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"Obviously not what I'm trying to achieve"* What are you trying to achieve? That might be useful information for us to actually help you.

Comment: `words` is `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>`.  Why would you expect an `operator[]` for it to ALSO produce a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>`??     More conventional usage of `operator[]` is to produce an element of a container  e.g. `std::string::operator[]()` produces a (reference to) a `char`.     Also, having a class member that is `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<string>>` is pointless - a member that is a simple `std::vector<std::string>` is correct - and less error prone.     And a class named `sort` .... Bleegh!

Comment: I believe that it first is probably your compiler, or build or "operator" needs a value to at least hold, try something else. Sorry if it didn't work M8
good luck.

Comment: Nitpick: "Retarded" is either an out-of-date medical term, or a technical chemical engineering term. You're not retarded, just ignorant. And hey, now you've learned! Also, if you want to post your own answer, [you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) -- you don't need to edit your question to contain the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `words` member is not an array or container.  It is a `std::shared_ptr`, which does not have an `operator[]` defined prior to C++17 (and even then, your code would still be using it wrong). That is why your `operator[]` fails to compile.

You have a `std::shared_ptr` pointing to a `std::vector<std::string>` object stored somewhere else in memory <sup>1</sup>.  If you want your `operator[]` to access the `std::string` values in that `std::vector`, you need to deference the pointer first in order to access the `std::vector`, and then you can call its `operator[]`.  You need to fix the return value of your `operator[]` to be a single `std::string`, not a `std::shared_ptr`.

<sup>1: why are you using a pointer at all? Why not declare `words` to be an actual `std::vector` object directly in your class? `std::vector<std::string> words;`</sup>

Try this instead:

class.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class sort
{
public:

    //...

    std::string& operator [](size_t st);

    //...

private:

    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> words;
    std::string alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

};
```

class.cpp

```
#include "sort.h"

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

//...

std::string& sort::operator[](size_t st) 
{
    return (*words)[st];
}

//...
```

Comment: Sigh. +1 for catching that the function prototype needs to be changed too. I missed that completely. Can't believe I did.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably the fact that `words` is a `std::shared_ptr`, not an `std::vector`. `std::shared_ptr::operator[]()` [is a C++17 thing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) (meaning it won't compile in C++11), and even then it doesn't do what you think it does:

> **Return value**
>
> A reference to the idx-th element of the array, i.e., get()[idx]

Then, from [`get()`'s documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get):

> std::shared_ptr::get
>
> T* get() const noexcept; (until C++17)
>
> element_type* get() const noexcept; (since C++17)

Meaning that `get()` returns a pointer. Together, this effectively makes your code the same as:

```
std::vector<int>* ptr = nullptr; // Note that this data is probably  allocated some how...
// Then, later...
ptr[index];
```

That is not what is appears you want. This is basically the functional equivalent of accessing the `index`th element of an array of vectors (it's more complicated than that, but I don't know enough about the technical differences between pointers and arrays to articulate it properly here). What you want is the `operator[]()` of the dereferenced pointer like this:

```
(*ptr)[index]; // Parenthesis for clarity. I don't think that they are technically necessary here.
```

What this boils down to is this: what you (probably) want is [`std::shared_ptr`'s dereference operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*):

```
 return (*words)[st]; // again, parenthesis for clarity here.
                     // I don't think they are technically necessary here, either.
```

That should compile and do what you want.

**Edit:** It has come to my attention, thanks to [Remy Lebeau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56962488/10957435), that your function prototype will need to change as well, as `(*words)[st]` is not a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>`, it is merely as `std::string`. Thus, change the prototype to this instead:

> ```
> std::string& operator [](size_t st);
> ```

And in the cpp:

> ```
> std::string& sort::operator[](size_t st) 
> {
>    return (*words)[st];
> }
> ```